# Custom Django url path converter (comma separated integers)

Tags: python, django, regex

I am trying to create custom path converter to parse following type of url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/archives/tvseries/129/delete-image/352,353,354/
```

in order to extract comma separated integers list from last part of the url `/352,353,354/`  and  use it in the view in `self.kwargs`.

My url config:

```
register_converter(archives.converters.CommaSeparatedIntegersPathConverter, 'int_list')

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'tvseries/<int:series_pk>/upload-image/<str:filename>/',
        archives.views.FileUploadView.as_view(),
        name='upload'
    ),
    path(
        'tvseries/<int:series_pk>/delete-image/<int_list:image_pk>/',
        archives.views.FileUploadView.as_view(),
        name='delete-image'
    ),
]
```

converter in `converters.py`

```
class CommaSeparatedIntegersPathConverter:

    regex = '^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return [int(v) for v in value.split(',')]

    def to_url(self, value):
        return ','.join(map(str, value))
```

I keep receiving exception  404 on this configuration . Tried few regex I found in internet on  comma separated integers list -same 404.

What's wrong?

Comment: Remove `^` in the regex, you will then get the numbers at the end of the string.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Unfortunatelly doesnt work this way

Comment: Try `regex = '(?<=/)\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=/?$)'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew .last one workerd! Thanks. You could write full answer. I will confirm it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
regex = r'(?<=/)\d+(?:,\d+)*(?=/?$)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uNO8BN/1).

The regex means:

- `(?<=/)` - match a location immediately preceded with a `/`  char
- `\d+(?:,\d+)*` - 1+ digits and then 0 or more occurrences of a comma and 1+ digits
- `(?=/?$)` - immediately to the right, there must be an optional `/` and then end of string.